# Add helper error messages to user created functions

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have this function in SQL Server 2014:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[jdate_practice] 
     (@p1 INT,
      @p2 CHAR(8)) 
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @v2 DATETIME
    SET @v2 = CAST(@p2 AS DATETIME)

    RETURN ((DATEPART(yyyy, @v2) * 12) + 
             DATEPART(mm, @v2)) - ((@p1 * 12) + 6) 
END
```

such that

```
select dbo.jdate_practice(2018, '20180701')
```

returns the number 1 due to 2018 being the start of the fiscal year and 20180701 being the first month in the fiscal year.

I want to include an error handling functionality so that if any arguments are not supplied, instead of giving the default

> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied...

the function would return

> Please input a year in format YYYY for @p1

or

> Please input a date in format YYYYMMDD for @p2

I have tried writing this myself with some understanding of `IF` statements and `THROW` statement, but couldn't get the function syntax correct for creation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to handle that in your database function as opposed to on the UI side or in the business logic? Is this something an end user is going to call?

Comment: This function was built for database users to create a column that sequentially numbers the months in a fiscal year such that we won't need to write case when statements anymore

Comment: If it were a stored procedure, you could give the parameters default values and then check if any values were passed in. In functions, however, the user needs to pass in `DEFAULT` for defaults, so that's not going to work for what you want to do. In your shoes, I would validate the parameter values and let the database warn the user if they didn't pass in the requisite number of parameters.